# Should I upload a blinded manuscript for the final minor revision in editorialmanager?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I have submitted a paper to a journal from which it got a major revision before. Now, the revised version got a final minor revision suggestion before acceptance.

In the uploading section of the editorial manager, it still asks me to upload a blinded manuscript as a requirement. However, considering that this is the final revision, should I also upload the non-blinded version of the paper which includes the authors' names?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to do what the journal says it requires, they should know this better than anybody else. After acceptance, there will be a process involving typesetting and proof-reading. You might then be asked to provide a version including the author names, or the journal might add the author names during typesetting from information given during the submission process.